# Can i make cname point to remote URL directory

Tags: linux, dns, amazon-web-services, nameserver, cname

I have the remote url like this

`http://www.abc.com/my data/files` and i want to make my subdomain point to

this like

media.mydomain.com to that so that if i have file like

`http://www.abc.com/my data/files/abc.pdf` then i can serve it via

`media.mydomain.com/abc.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Create two virtual hosts in apache configuration with different DocumentRoot.
Something like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.abc.com
    ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc
        <Directory /var/www/abc>
        ...
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName media.mydomain.com
    ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc/my_data/files
        <Directory /var/www/abc/my_data/files>
        ...
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: the domain `abc.com` is not my personal domain , its external domain. will it work

Comment: @user1721949 : Do you mean that abc.com and media.mydomain.com located on different servers and you haven't access to abc.com server? In this case it(my solution) will not work.

Comment: yes u r right. is there any other way like htaccess or alias that will work